# Add customer attribute to catalog price rules in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

***I need to extend the functionality of Magento Catalog price rules.***

I want to be possible to have a rule or a field to have the possibility to select the country where the rule should apply.

So basically, I select Italy, the rule should only apply on frontend to customers logged with an address located in Italy.

I assume it's linked to catalogrule_product_price table where I should probably add columns (As how the customer_group is managed) but I don't know how to properly modify the code in the indexer to have :

```
 1. The correct prices indexed
 2. The correct prices displayed on frontend
```

I'm also interested in a solution for any customer attributes :)

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a row to the catalogrule table. Use the Setup Script to achieve this

```
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable('catalogrule'),
            'new_column',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 32,
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'comment' => 'New Column'
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    } 
}
```

If you need that to be displayed in the UI form, then add the new column in the Vendor/Namespace/view/adminhtml/ui_component/catalog_rule_form.xml XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="rule_information">
        <field name="test_column">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Test Column</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">test_column</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```